# WebSphere MQ Creating Remote Queue

Tags: ibm-mq

Why doesn't the following create the LOCAL quue definition? I see a remote queue definition with the name REMOTE_QUEUE? Do I need to create another DEFINE QLOCAL for LOCAL_QUEUE?

> DEFINE QREMOTE (LOCAL_QUEUE) RNAME (REMOTE_QUEUE)
>   RQMNAME(REMOTE_QUEUE_MANAGER) XMITQ(REMOTE_QUEUE_MANAGER) REPLACE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue `DEFINE QREMOTE(LOCAL_QUEUE)` you are making a routing entry that tells WMQ "any time someone on *this* QMgr opens a queue named `LOCAL_QUEUE` then instead, use *these* values for the queue name, the QMgr name and, if specified, resolve to this XMitQ".  This entry shows up when you list all the defined queues but it isn't a queue that can hold messages.  The only way to create a queue that can hold messages is `DEFINE QLOCAL`.

The next step is to define the actual target queue where messages can land.  Defining the QRemote on the local QMgr does not also define the QLocal on the target QMgr.  To do that, you would need to sign onto the target QMgr with Explorer or connect on the command line using `runmqsc` and issue the `DEFINE QLOCAL(REMOTE_QUEUE)` there.

It is a bit unfortunate that your example used names like `REMOTE_QUEUE` because on `REMOTE_QUEUE_MANAGER` it is actually a QLocal.

FYI - totally unrelated but you might want to consider using dots as name separators like `REMOTE.QUEUE` instead of `REMOTE_QUEUE` since WMQ recognizes these as node separators and authorization wildcards respect them.

Comment: Oh, I made up those names, believe that is not how I have it in my real code :). Let me rephrase my question, when I execute the define qremote command with a different name for local queue from the remote queue, I do not see the remote queue (or its local representation) listed in websphere mq explorer. however i can see it within runmqsc using dis q(*)

Comment: Never mind, it was the authrec, once rectified i am able to see it, thanks.